# How to read file Attribute such as "Author" or "Creator" in a directory using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-os

I am trying to fetch the modified date and Author of the files in a folder.

import os
 PATH="my folder/books"
 my_list= os.listdir(PATH)

Let us suppose

> customer details.xlsx

is one  of the files in the books folder

How can i fetch the Author or Creator of the customer details.xlsx using os module of python?

Also i am able to fetch modified time by using  os.path.getmtime(PATH/customer detalis.xlsx). But could not find the method  for getting the Author.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find the owner of a file or directory in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830618/how-to-find-the-owner-of-a-file-or-directory-in-python)

Comment: FYI, indent code blocks 4 spaces to format them properly

Answer (score 0):

This should work on UNIX:

```
import os, pwd

uid = os.stat("/path/to/file").st_uid
print pwd.getpwuid(uid).pw_name
```