# How to find the owner of a file in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, file-ownership

Same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830618/how-to-find-the-owner-of-a-file-or-directory-in-python), but for Windows.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830635/5069105) works nicely in Linux:

```
from os import stat
from pwd import getpwuid

def find_owner(filename):
    return getpwuid(stat(filename).st_uid).pw_name
```

The module `pwd` doesn't seem to be available in Windows.

How to do that in Windows?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086412/howto-determine-file-owner-on-windows-using-python-without-pywin32?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-the-owner-of-a-file.html

Comment: Both solutions tested and work fine, ie, I've managed to pull file owner username using both approaches. Using `win32security` seems a lot simpler.

Comment: With ctypes, we have to implement much of the solution at a low level, in terms of data structures, functions/methods, and even some memory management (i.e. calling `LocalFree`). However, it's useful if we wish to avoid depending on PyWin32, which is a rather large dependency.