# From a file's information, how can I get the "Owner" of it using Python?

Tags: python, file, directory, attributes, file-ownership

In a VERY filled directory on Windows operating system with hundreds of sub-directories and thousands of files, I'm trying to pull out where the files (raw path + file name) are along with the 'Owner' attribute of the file and log that; essentially a simple two column table with FILE and OWNER. I don't really care about the output format (.csv, .xls, xlsx, etc.) as long as it can be written out and is structured - I am focusing on getting the output first. Here is my attempt with dir as an example.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

file_list=[]
owner_list=[]

dir = r'Downloads'
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(dir):
    for file in f:
        file_list.append(os.path.join(r, file))
        owner_list.append('???')

df = pd.DataFrame({'File': [file_list],
                  'Owner': [owner_list]})
print(df)
```

I'm having a very hard time getting the owner attribute. With Google's help, I don't think

> stat(my_filename).st_uid

-is the right function to use because it's returning an ID instead of an actual name. What are some possible solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to find the owner of a file or directory in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830618/how-to-find-the-owner-of-a-file-or-directory-in-python)